# Compare two images, keep different pixels, set same pixels to transparent in actionscript 3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Ok, the question is pretty much in the title.

What I want to do is filter out differing pixels from one image and a default image.  Then "print" only those pixels on a transparent layer if you will.  Such that if you would "merge" the default image with the transparent layer, you would end up with the other image.

Is that possible with actionscript 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

[`BitmapData.compare()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29) is nearly what you want. It gives you a new `BitmapData` object where each pixel is the difference between the corresponding pixels in the two `BitmapData` objects being compared.

It sounds like you want the actual value of the changed pixels. I don't know of a built-in way to do that, so you might have to go through and do it pixel-by-pixel using `BitmapData.getPixel()` or building a PixelBender filter to do it. Either route is likely slower than you really want to deal with, honestly (I built a Chromakey demo app for a sales pitch that was barely able to scrape 8fps using those methods)